# Stack around the variable 'sortArray' was corrupted

Tags: c++, arrays, memory, runtime-error

Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'sortArray' was corrupted.

I am getting this on final line, the program is meant to create a list of random numbers and then sort them(WIP). I thought it might be the array size being smaller than the number of lines in test.txt so I increased it from 100 to 101 to no avail.

```
//#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>  
#include <ctime>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    //srand(time(NULL));
    std::ofstream outfile("C:\\Users\\smasher248\\Desktop\\test.txt");
    int randomNumber;
    for (int x = 0; x < 100; x++)
    {
        randomNumber = rand() % 9000 + 1000;
        outfile << randomNumber <<"\n";

    }

    outfile.close();
    std::ifstream infile("C:\\Users\\smasher248\\Desktop\\test.txt");
    std::string lineHolder;
    int lineCounter = 0;
    int sortArray[101];
    while (std::getline(infile, lineHolder))
    {
        sortArray[lineCounter] = stoi(lineHolder);
        cout << sortArray[lineCounter] << "\n";
        lineCounter++;
    }
    infile.close();
    int swapContainer;
    for (int i = 0; i < 101; i++)
    {
        if (sortArray[i] > sortArray[i+1])
        {
            swapContainer = sortArray[i];
            sortArray[i] = sortArray[i + 1];
            sortArray[i + 1] = swapContainer;
        }
        std::ofstream sortedFile("C:\\Users\\smasher248\\Desktop\\test_sorted.txt");

        sortedFile << sortArray[i] << "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Your loops reaches `i == 100` where `sortArray[i+1]` dereferences `sortArray[101]`.

Comment: Your sorting loop doesn't sort.

Comment: `std::sort(sortArray, sortArray + lineCounter);` -- That properly sorts your array.

Comment: `randomNumber = rand() % 9000 + 1000;` - That modulo introduces bias into your random numbers. That *may* or *may not* be acceptable.

Comment: Was the code edited after the first comment? The bug still applies but the sizes are 1 larger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to make a few changes into your code.

- Include `<algorithm>` in the beginning of your code
- In the `ofstream(...)`, add `..., std::ios::app)` to append into the file.
- To sort the array, remove the entire block of conditional expression above the `ofstream` syntax and add `std::sort(sortArray, sortArray + 100)` **outside of the loop**.
- Change the value `101` to `100` in that For loop.

And you're done.